# PHP Database not adding data

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, mysqli

I use a try/catch statement in this PHP but my code is executing the catch statement but not sure why, here's the JSON message produced in the catch.

```
{"success":0,"message":"Database Error1. Please Try Again!"}
```

The code is follows below

```
$query        = " SELECT 1 FROM tbl_client WHERE master_username = :user";
$query2        = " SELECT 1 FROM tbl_client WHERE institution_pin = :institution_pin";


$query_params = array(
    ':user' => $_POST['username']
);

$query_params2 = array(
    ':institution_pin' => $_POST['institution_pin']
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
try { 
$stmt   = $db->prepare($query2);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params2);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, someone has already chosen that PIN, choose another!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
```

I have looked over the code but nothing is jumping out as incorrect, maybe I am missing something?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the thrown exception `$ex`. If you temporarily remove your try-catch block, php will show you exactly what is wrong. Or you dump whatever `$ex` contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert

```
$response["error"] = $ex;
```

in your catch statement so you see what exception happens and triggers the catch.

Comment: I have amended my code and still receive the same JSON message, any ideas?

Comment: You receive exactly the same message? Did you edit both catch statements where your message is "Database Error1. Please Try Again!"?

Comment: Yes I did but still nothing different, is there a better way to code this solution then?

Comment: You could try to just echo the $ex message, because I'm not sure about the json part with whom I'm not really familiar. Or as jeroen mentioned temporarily remove your try-catch block...